# my code won't print anything

Tags: java, if-statement

Hey so I have a code here designed to give the best rate on a car rental with the weekly and daily prices as constants. The code will take the color, type of rental, and amount of days but does not output anything. Am I missing something?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class lab3
 {
    public static final char E = 'E';
    public static final int ZERO = 0;
    public static final double ECONOMY_DAILY = 25.5;
    public static final double FULL_DAILY = 39.4;
    public static final double ECONOMY_WEEKLY = 120.5;
    public static final double FULL_WEEKLY = 216.25;
    public static void main (String[] args)
     {
        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
        System.out.println("Enter the color of the vehicle:");
        String color = Keyboard.next();

        System.out.println ("Economy or Full:");
        String Type = Keyboard.next();
        char FirstTypeLetter = Type.toUpperCase()
        .charAt(0); 
        System.out.println("For how many days?");
        int Days = Keyboard.nextInt();
        int Weeks = Days/7;
        int DaysLeftover = Days%7;
        switch (FirstTypeLetter)
        {
            case 'E':
            double Rate1 = Weeks * ECONOMY_WEEKLY;
            double Rate2 = (Weeks * ECONOMY_WEEKLY) + (Days * ECONOMY_DAILY);
            double Rate3 = (Days * ECONOMY_DAILY);
            if ((Rate1 > Rate2)&(Rate1>Rate3))
                            {
                                System.out.println("This is the best rate for a" + " " + color + " " + Type + " vehicle for" + " " + Days + "days:" + Rate1);
                                if ((Rate2>Rate1)&(Rate2>Rate3))
                                {
                                    System.out.println("This is the best rate for a" + " " + color + " " + Type + " vehicle for" + " " + Days + "days:" + Rate2);
                                }

                                        else if ((Rate3>Rate2) & (Rate3>Rate1))
                                        {
                                            System.out.println("This is the best rate for a" + " " + color + " " + Type + " vehicle for" + " " + Days + "days:" + Rate3);
    switch (FirstTypeLetter)
    {
            case 'F':
            double FullRate1 = Weeks * FULL_WEEKLY;
            double FullRate2 = (Weeks * FULL_WEEKLY) + (Days * FULL_DAILY);
            double FullRate3 = (Days * ECONOMY_DAILY);
            if ((Rate1 > Rate2) & (Rate1 > Rate3))
            {
                System.out.println("This is the best rate for a" + " " + color + " " + Type + " vehicle for" + " " + Days + "days:" + FullRate1);
            }
            if ((FullRate2 > FullRate1) & (FullRate2 > FullRate3))
            {
                System.out.println("This is the best rate for a" + " " + color + " " + Type + " vehicle for" + " " + Days + "days:" + FullRate2);
            }
            else if ((FullRate3 > FullRate1) & (FullRate3 > FullRate2))
            {
                System.out.println("This is the best rate for a" + " " + color + " " + Type + " vehicle for" + " " + Days + "days:" + FullRate3);
            }
            break;
            default:
            System.out.println("Try Again!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest that you use the Format Code option in your IDE to help you see the nesting levels in your code. If you are using a plain text editor, you should learn about formatting conventions so that you can format your code to make it easier for you to follow what is going on.

Comment: You should also learn how to use a debugger so that you can step through your code and view the values of variables to figure out what your code is actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make sense.

In your `case 'E'` you have another switch statment which is using the same variables and then checking it for `case 'F'`

Also when using the `if` statment you are using `&` instead of `&&`

As you only have two cases `E` and `F` I suggest you use a simple `if` statment

```
if (FirstTypeLetter == 'E' && Rate1 > Rate2 && Rate1>Rate3)
{
}
```

Comment: Ok I took off the second switch statement but it gives me an orphaned case error

Comment: Please read my updated answer.  One biggy is your erroneous ands `&&` NOT `&`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you formatted your switch statement incorrectly.
It should look like this:

```
double Rate1 = Weeks * ECONOMY_WEEKLY;
    double Rate2 = (Weeks * ECONOMY_WEEKLY) + (Days * ECONOMY_DAILY);
    double Rate3 = (Days * ECONOMY_DAILY);
    switch (FirstTypeLetter) {
        case 'E':
            if ((Rate1 > Rate2) & (Rate1 > Rate3)) {
                System.out.println("This is the best rate for a" + " " + color + " " + Type + " vehicle for" + " " + Days + "days:" + Rate1);
            }
            else if ((Rate2 > Rate1) & (Rate2 > Rate3)){
                System.out.println("This is the best rate for a" + " " + color + " " + Type + " vehicle for" + " " + Days + "days:" + Rate2);
            }
            else if ((Rate3 > Rate2) & (Rate3 > Rate1)) {
                System.out.println("This is the best rate for a" + " " + color + " " + Type + " vehicle for" + " " + Days + "days:" + Rate3);
            }
            break;
        case 'F':
            double FullRate1 = Weeks * FULL_WEEKLY;
            double FullRate2 = (Weeks * FULL_WEEKLY) + (Days * FULL_DAILY);
            double FullRate3 = (Days * ECONOMY_DAILY);
            if ((Rate1 > Rate2) & (Rate1 > Rate3)) {
                System.out.println("This is the best rate for a" + " " + color + " " + Type + " vehicle for" + " " + Days + "days:" + FullRate1);
            }
            else if ((FullRate2 > FullRate1) & (FullRate2 > FullRate3)) {
                System.out.println("This is the best rate for a" + " " + color + " " + Type + " vehicle for" + " " + Days + "days:" + FullRate2);
            }
            else if ((FullRate3 > FullRate1) & (FullRate3 > FullRate2)) {
                System.out.println("This is the best rate for a" + " " + color + " " + Type + " vehicle for" + " " + Days + "days:" + FullRate3);
            }
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Try Again!");
            break;
       }
```

[Here is a good example of switch statements in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)